# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysite' django application

Tags: django

Good morning,

I have read other similar posts but I still cannot solve my problem. Could anyone point out to me into the right direction?

From one moment to another I started getting the following error. I have not made any changes to the settings.py file. The last feature that I installed, was the Django avatar package which has been running without problems.
The error that I get is the following: " ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysite'"

Settings.py:

```
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-oqv&!@ek#@_p9d#_oe3uxyrm-k&pvht4fm6xlk1o53hxib4k+o'
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [

'simple_investing.apps.SimpleInvestingConfig',
'django.contrib.admin', #Admin site
'django.contrib.auth', #An authentication system.
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.sites',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'allauth',
'allauth.account',
'allauth.socialaccount',
'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',     
'crispy_forms',
'avatar',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 ]
 ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

 TEMPLATES = [
     {
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
]
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [

# Needed to login by username in Django admin, regardless of `allauth`
'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',

# `allauth` specific authentication methods, such as login by e-mail
'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',

]
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
   'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
}

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "/"
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = "/"
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = "none"

SITE_ID = 1
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
'google': {
    # For each OAuth based provider, either add a ``SocialApp``
    # (``socialaccount`` app) containing the required client
    # credentials, or list them here:
    'APP': {
        'client_id': '520936870130-fcg82fmcl4j0gcia2ol5c3ojq1q113tv.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        'secret': 'it1jqY-9LsIdAAKWQw9VZX_X',
        'key': ''
    }
},
```

}

Hereunder, is a picture of my application root's directory. [image]

In addition, hereunder is a picture of the problem
[image]

Comment: You might need to replace all `mysite.*` with ***`simple_investing.mysite.*`***

Comment: I tried to do that but it did not work.

Comment: mysite on your simple_investing is appliction of your project?? if yes you should add this in your INSTALLED_APPS  on your setting

Comment: I found the error. The name of my project is mysite. The inner mysite directory is where the actual python package for the project lives. By mistake, I moved it inside my application (simple_investing). By placing the inner mysite back to the project folder (outer mysite) the problem was solved.  Hope this helps someone in the future.